# Deleting a range of calendar events with Microsoft Graph is not including the "All Day" events on the boundary

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to purge a set of calendar events using Microsoft Graph.

This is my filter string:

`start/dateTime ge '2020-10-26T00:00' and end/dateTime le '2020-11-01T23:59'`

I noticed that in some instances any calendar event on the Sunday was not being deleted in that week.

On further inspection this only happens when the event has the "All Day" flag set.

So, when my events have a start / end time it picks up all the events within that complete week. But if (and it does happen) the user sets the Sunday event as a "all day" event with no time range, it does not get picked up and deleted.

This is my current delete routine:

```
   public async Task<bool> DeleteCalendarEvents(SettingsBase oSettings)
    {
        try
        {
            //var oCalendar = await _graphClient.Me.Calendars[oSettings.CalendarID].Request().GetAsync();
            //string strName = oCalendar.Name;

            var oEvents = await _graphClient
                                    .Me
                                    .Calendars[oSettings.CalendarID]
                                    .Events
                                    .Request()
                                    .Select("Start,Subject,Id") // TODO: Is there any point doing this?
                                    .Top(50)
                                    .Filter(oSettings.GetFilterString())
                                    .OrderBy("start/DateTime")
                                    .GetAsync();

            //Program.file.WriteLine($"Calendar {strName}");
            List<Event> listEvents = new List<Event>();

            listEvents.AddRange(oEvents);
            while (oEvents.NextPageRequest != null)
            {
                oEvents = await oEvents.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                listEvents.AddRange(oEvents);
            }

            foreach (Event oEvent in listEvents)
            { 
                //Program.file.WriteLine($"Event Data: {oEvent.Start.DateTime} Id: {oEvent.Id} Subject: {oEvent.Subject}");
                await _graphClient.Me.Events[oEvent.Id].Request().DeleteAsync();
            }

            //Program.file.WriteLine($"Count: {listEvents.Count}" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SimpleLog.Log(ex);
            Console.WriteLine("DeleteCalendarEvents: See error log.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I need it to factor in these all day events too because I am now getting duplicates.

I am using Microsoft Graph 3.2 with Visual C# on VS2019.

Note: This method for deleting events was originally discussed and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46279381/deleting-calendar-events-with-microsoft-graph-why-do-i-need-to-call-multiple-t) but I was not aware of this glitch with "all day" events on the limit.

---

Is anyone from the **Microsoft Graph** team actively looking for issues tagged for their attention? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it in POSTMAN or Graph Explorer? Do you see the same results as the MS Graph SDK?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I don’t know how to try the suggestions you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, I mean have you tried to delete an event having all day flag as true using [Graph Explore](https://aka.ms/ge) or POSTMAN so that we can understand if its happening from only SDK perspective or its happening Graph Server. Try using the id which is not getting deleted and try to delete it using postman using a simple Delete request.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity Sadly I have now deleted the temporary calendar that I was using. I figured this would be a straightforward test for the MS guys to test themselves.